# Getting all locales in java

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe, jbutton

The Question

Create a new project in Eclipse
• Create a JFrame application that contains ONE JButton with the label “List All Locales” and ONE JTextArea. Output ALL available Locales to the JTextArea when the JButton is pushed.

So I have the code working where it has the JButton but I can't seem to get it printing out all the Locales in the JTextArea when the button is pressed. Is there something I'm missing

My Code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

/**
* 
*/

/**
* @author Michelle
*
*/
public class Exercise1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    JButton button;
    JFrame frame;
    JTextArea ta;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Locale[] available = Calendar.getAvailableLocales();


public Exercise1(){

    Container c = getContentPane();
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    ta = new JTextArea(20,22);
    ta.setText("All Locales will display here");
    ta.setEditable(false);
    button = new JButton();
    button.setText("List all Locales");
    JScrollPane output = new JScrollPane(ta);
    button.addActionListener(this);
    p.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    p.add(output);
    c.add(p);


    setSize(300,300);
    setVisible(true);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
    // TO DO Auto-generated method stub
    if (a.getActionCommand().equals("List All Locales")){

        for(int i=0; i<available.length;i++){

            ta.append(available[i].getDisplayName()+"\n");
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Exercise1 myLocaleTest = new Exercise1();
        myLocaleTest.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
}
```

Comment: Your action check doesn't seem right to me. You seem to be checking for the label of the button!? Is there a button.setCommand(String) or something you're forgetting?

Comment: A quick Google turned up this method: `setActionCommand(String);` I'd suggest using than.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text on the button says "List all Locales"

```
button.setText("List all Locales");
```

In `actionPerformed`, you're checking if the action command is "List All Locales"

```
if (a.getActionCommand().equals("List All Locales")){
```

Do you see the difference between `"List all Locales"` and `"List All Locales"`?

To avoid this kind of mistake, you could create a constant in your class, and use that. For example:

```
public class Exercise1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private static final String BUTTON_ACTION = "List all Locales";

    public Exercise1(){
        // ...
        button.setText(BUTTON_ACTION);
        // ...
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        if (a.getActionCommand().equals(BUTTON_ACTION)){
            // ...
```

Comment: The label is used? What if there are multiple buttons with the same label text?

Comment: Why would you want to have multiple buttons with exactly the same text in the same window?

Comment: @munyul Then its developer's mistake.

Comment: @Jesper the reason should not matter, the ability to support it should be there! I'm sure SWT supports it.

Comment: @AJ, or it is a lack of vision/imagination from the library developers - that's another way to look at it.

Comment: *"the reason should not matter"*  If it results in an unusable GUI, it very much matters.  Don't make presumptions about what matters and what doesn't.  The API supports most things that make sense, little of what doesn't.

Comment: Thank you so much I feel like an idiot after you said that that's all that was wrong with a wrong character

Answer (score 2):

Change to equalsIgnoreCase instead...

```
if (a.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase("List all locales")){
```

Answer (score 1):

Misspelling here `if (a.getActionCommand().equals("List All Locales"))`. Button have next command `"List all Locales"`. Change that and all will be work.

Answer (score 1):

Others have already pointed out that your string check has an upper/lower case typo in it.

The suggestion to use a `static final` is good, but NOT for the button label! Why? Zero language support!

I did a quick search online and found the method: `setActionCommand(String);`

```
private static final String ACTION_COMMAND = "ac1";

...

JButton jbutton = new JButton();
jbutton.setText("My label text");
jbutton.setActionCommand(ACTION_COMMAND);

...

if ( action.getActionCommand().equals(ACTION_COMMAND) )
```

The `static final` should be used for setting the action command and for testing for the action, but not the label!